# Reading string from a text file and splitting it into separate array lists and comparing

Tags: java, file, arraylist, split, output

I'm new to programming in Java and am having some problems solving a problem using array lists and comparisons. The code below is not the attempted full problem but the problem is this:

Essentially read a text file that has a phone number and a double value beside it. `999-878-2233 37.23` then the next line would be `999-889-4664 20.33`. Then if a user would type in a value over 25, it should print the first line. Also, I can only loop up to 10 lines.

What I have so far is this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
  Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

  System.out.print ("Enter the filename: ");
  String fileName = input.nextLine();
  File file = new File(fileName);
  Scanner inputFile = new Scanner (file);
  String line;
  BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
  int i = 0;

    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    while(((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) && i < 10) 
    {
      System.out.println(line);
      i++;
      list.add(line);
    }         
  String[] lineList = list.toArray(new String[0]);

  System.out.println (Arrays.toString(lineList));
}
}
```

I know the split option with `line.split(" "))` is probably the best way forward. I assume the double value would be put into a separate array list and then compared to the user input and the phone number beside it. The phone number would remain a string and would be printed with it.

I appreciate the help if someone is willing.

================================================

I solved the problem using a different solution.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;  
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.regex.*;
public class labFinalA2
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
      Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
      int i = 0;
      double threshold;
      System.out.print ("Enter the filename: ");
      String fileName = input.nextLine();
      File file = new File(fileName);
      Scanner inputFile = new Scanner (file);
      String line;
      BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));

      System.out.print ("Cell bill threshold: ");
      threshold = input.nextDouble();

      System.out.println ("All cell phones bills at or above the threshold amount.");
      System.out.println ("      Number     Amount");

       while(((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) && i < 20) 
        {
          i++;
          String str = line;
          Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+))");
          Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
          while(m.find()) 
          {
          double d = Double.parseDouble(m.group());
          if (d >= threshold)
          {
          String cellBill = Double.toString(d);
          String phone = line.replaceFirst(Pattern.quote(cellBill), "");
          System.out.println(phone + "     "+ d);
          }
          else
          {
           inputFile.close();
        }
    }
}
}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! We are here for all kinds of specific programming questions. When you ask a question, it is best to describe a specific programming problem, something like "I expect the program to do this, but it does that". What you have done here is said "It doesn't work" and listed the program. That means that, to help you, we have to read the program and figure out where your problem is. There is no guarantee that what we find is the problem you're actually seeing, and it just becomes too much trouble. We don't want to guess.

Comment: Hello, the above code calls in the lines of the txt file and puts into an array of strings. The code does work. Was just looking for suggestions to solving the rest of the problem. Not the complete solution.

Comment: After reading your comment response, and rereading the question again, I have NO idea what you're asking.

Comment: Hey, I appreciate you're feedback. I'll try to do a better job next time in asking the question. I updated the post with code that solved the problem. The solution is different from what I was doing before.